# How to use a static map of function pointer field in a template with using or typedef

Tags: c++11

I have

```
template <class ElemType>
class FunctionNode : public ComputationNode<ElemType>
{
    typedef void(*TensorFunctionFunc)  (TensorView<ElemType>&);

    static const map <string, TensorFunctionFunc> fmap;
```

and in the cpp

```
template <class ElemType>
const map <string, TensorFunctionFunc> FunctionNode::fmap = FunctionNode::create_map();
```

However i get a variety of errors , tried using as well. Any ideas ? Also i don't think i can use std::function() since i'm using dlopen.

Quite a few similar questions but none covering a static map of function pointer , in a template .

This is not a duplicate of "Why can templates only be implemented in the header file? 12 answers" since even when using the header it does not work due to the static ! . This requires completely different initialization.  ( the answers there do not work) ..

Comment: I have explained how its different but it still marked duplicate ..